# Error while integrating spring with hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to integrate spring with hibernate but i get this error:

> [2017-10-06 05:26:14,475] Artifact spring-mvc-hibernate-example:war: `java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in com.boraji.tutorial.spring.config.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution. Please see server.log for more details.`

Here are some files:

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.boraji.tutorial.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-hibernate-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mysql Connector -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP Dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          <version>1.8.0-alpha2</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Initializer:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer
      extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

**application config**:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.boraji.tutorial.spring.dao"),
      @ComponentScan("com.boraji.tutorial.spring.service") })
public class AppConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

      Properties props = new Properties();
      // Setting JDBC properties
      props.put(DRIVER, env.getProperty("mysql.driver"));
      props.put(URL, env.getProperty("mysql.url"));
      props.put(USER, env.getProperty("mysql.user"));
      props.put(PASS, env.getProperty("mysql.password"));

      // Setting Hibernate properties
      props.put(SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
      props.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
      props.put(DIALECT, env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

      // Setting C3P0 properties
      props.put(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, 
            env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size"));
      props.put(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, 
            env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size"));
      props.put(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT,
            env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment"));
      props.put(C3P0_TIMEOUT, 
            env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout"));
      props.put(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, 
            env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"));

      factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
      factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
      return factoryBean;
   }

   @Bean
   public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
      HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
      return transactionManager;
   }
}
```

db.properties:

```
# MySQL properties
mysql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
mysql.user=root
mysql.password=root

# Hibernate propert[2017-10-06 05:26:14,475] Artifact spring-mvc-hibernate-example:war: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in com.boraji.tutorial.spring.config.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution. Please see server.log for more details.ies
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

#C3P0 properties
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=150
```

UserDao:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImp implements UserDao {

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


   public void save(User user) {
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
   }


   public List<User> list() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      TypedQuery<User> query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User");
      return query.getResultList();
   }

}
```

I saw lots of similar problems here but it didn't help. What could go wrong in my application?

Answer (score 0):

DRIVER, URL, USER and PASS are all static fields. Make sure you imported all of them. Plus, make sure you imported the spring Environment (not the hibernate).

```
import static org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
```